# PhantomJS No Such File or Directory on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to run PhantomJS on CentOS. I have used [this page](http://attester.ariatemplates.com/usage/phantom.html) as a primer for installing it.

HOWEVER, when I go to run the `version` command, I get command not found.

I have verified that the file is 64bit and that I am running a 64it OS.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes: you showed us where your system searches for phantomjs, not where the executable is located. FFor `phantomjs` to work, it should be located in one of the directories specified by PATH, not in one of their subdirectories. Pls make sure that a copy of the executable is located in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your executable lacks x attribute. Make `chmod +x phantomjs` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. The instructions you pointed to refer to installation on Windows, but I assume you bent these to apply to a real CentOS installation.
2. As @Dmitry_Teslenko suggests, ensure the file has executable-bit set.
3. Call the file explicitly, since it does not appear to be in your path

   ```
   # from the directory where the phantomjs binary file exists on disk:
   ./phantomjs --version
   ```
4. You can add the binary to the path in several ways:

   ```
   # link the file into a directory already in the path:
   sudo ln -l ./phantomjs /usr/local/bin
   # copy the file into a directory already in the path:
   sudo cp -p ./phantomjs /usr/local/bin
   # add the directory to the path:
   export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
   ```